# How to invoke four or more than four different classes with same method by invoking only one class?

Tags: java

So I've four different classes class A, Class B, Class C, and Class D, all these classes have a method with the same name abc(); 
How do I declare only one class in the main method which should automatically invoke all the other methods in the other classes?

```
class A
{
    void abc()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
class B
{
    void  abc()
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
class C
{
    void abc()
    {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
class D
{
    void abc()
    {
        System.out.println("D");
    }
}

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        D obj3 = new D();


    }

}
```

Comment: Taking a Socratic approach: If you have a group of actions you want to group together in code, how do you do that?

Comment: Look at using an interface and collection.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do (and why). Do you want `D` to invoke `C` and `C` to invoke `B` etc ?

Comment: @c0der Yes.... and no I want D to invoke all... is that possible?

Comment: So, you want to have a class that invokes all of the other classes? An interface would help with that, not an actual class, unless you get into nesting of classes perhaps, not really sure the exact question or why you would want this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe an interface would help with this, look at [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html) for more help on the subject.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I couldn't comment at the time, hence my level. lol

Answer (score 1):

The methods "abc" are not declared with the static keyword. You have to instantiate an instance of A, B, C, and D (perhaps [anonymously](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)) to invoke the abc method.

You can use Reflection to get about this, but I don't really recommend it.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class A
{
    void abc()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
class B
{
    void  abc()
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
class C
{
    void abc()
    {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
class D
{
    void abc()
    {
        System.out.println("D");
    }
}

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

    Class classes[] = { A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class };

        for (Class c : classes) {
            Object x = c.newInstance();
            Method abc = c.getDeclaredMethod("abc");
            abc.invoke(x);
        }

    }

}
```

The easier way to get about this is to use an interface. Still using a little bit of reflection, it could look like this:

```
interface Abc {
    void abc();
}
class A implements Abc
{
    @Override
    public void abc()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
class B implements Abc
{
    @Override
    public void  abc()
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
class C implements Abc
{
    @Override
    public void abc()
    {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
class D implements Abc
{
    @Override
    public void abc()
    {
        System.out.println("D");
    }
}

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    Class classes[] = { A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class };

        for (Class c : classes) {
            Abc x = (Abc) c.newInstance();
            x.abc();
        }

    }

}
```